# Drawing thread interaction

Tags: design, uml, multithreading

I'd like to draw (pen and pencils) threads interaction in a UML(-like) notation. I don't insist on UML, anything that is obvious to the reader should do.

I started with sequence diagrams, but I don't feel this is the best way to do that. All the time, there would be "action initiators" coming from off-screen which kinda break the SSD idea. I inherited a medium size code base with around 9 - 10 threads each owning a state machine and I'm trying to figure out how it works.

How should I visualize thread interaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory has some good guides on Parallel Computing and Programming. In particular, the guide to [Posix Threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) has some very well done charts that illustrate how to visualize threads and their interaction.