# What is the best way to diagrammatically represent a system threading architecture?

Tags: design, architecture, multithreading

I am yet to find the perfect way to diagrammatically represent the overall threading architecture for a system (using UML or otherwise).

I am after a diagramming technique that would show all the threads in a given system and how they interact with each other. There are a few similar questions - [Drawing Thread Interaction](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115833/drawing-thread-interaction), [UML Diagrams of Multithreaded Applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120859/uml-diagrams-of-multi-threaded-applications) and [Intuitive UML Approach to Depict Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954193/is-there-an-inituitive-uml-approach-to-depict-threads) but they don't fully answer my question.

What are some of the techniques that you've found useful to depict the overall threading architecture for a system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are some of the techniques that you've found useful to depict the overall threading architecture for a system?

By not treating it special. Elements in the architecture send messages to one another; if that's across a thread boundary (or even a system boundary) doesn't really matter from an architectural perspective.

As far as implementation goes, it doesn't matter. Implementation is done at the module level. Black Box A presents some interface and consumes some other Black Box. Make a note that the interface it consumes or provides is required to be (non)blocking and/or threadsafe and be on your way.

Otherwise, consider it a design smell if those threading details are leaking through your abstractions.

Comment: Great answer, whether a subsystem uses another thread or not is implementation detail.